# Why does this data binding not change the GridUnitType?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridsplitter, gridlength

My goal is to save a `GridSplitter` position for later recall.  The splitter is inside a `Grid` control that has three columns defined thusly:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding GridPanelWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />  <!--splitter itself is in this column-->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The property `GridPanelWidth` is defined this way in the view model:

```
private GridLength _gridPanelWidth = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
public GridLength GridPanelWidth
{
    get { return _gridPanelWidth; }
    set
    {
        if (_gridPanelWidth != value)
            SetProperty(ref _gridPanelWidth, value, () => GridPanelWidth);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that when the splitter is moved, the binding updates only the `Double` (Value) component of the bound property, but not the `GridUnitType` part of it.

Example:  the property defaults to `1*`.  User drags the splitter and the value becomes `354*`, instead of just `354`.  On restoring the value, then, it's huge (354 times, not 354 pixels).

Why is this happening, and what would you do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding GridPanelWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
        <!--splitter itself is in this column-->
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RightColumn" Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border
        BorderBrush="Gray"
        BorderThickness="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.Row="0"
        />

    <GridSplitter
        Background="SteelBlue"
        ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
        ResizeDirection="Columns"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        ShowsPreview="False"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="0"
        />

    <Border
        BorderBrush="Gray"
        BorderThickness="1"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Grid.Row="0"
        />

    <StackPanel
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Grid.Column="0"
        >
        <TextBlock>
            <Run>GridPanelWidth: </Run>
            <Run Text="{Binding GridPanelWidth.Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Run Text="{Binding GridPanelWidth.GridUnitType, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run>RightColumn.Width: </Run>
            <Run Text="{Binding Width.Value, ElementName=RightColumn, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Run Text="{Binding Width.GridUnitType, ElementName=RightColumn, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

Screenshot 3:

[image]

*Res ipsa loquitor*, as far as I'm concerned, but just to be on the safe side:

Because the parent may be resized, the grid splitter changes the ratio between the two columns, while preserving the `GridUnitType.Star` for each one so that when the parent is resized, the ratio will naturally remain constant. This preserves the intent of the initial Width values in the XAML.

`Width.Value` for the left column turns out to be identical to the left Border's `ActualWidth`, and the same holds true for the right column. You'll have to grab both and save the ratio.

### Update

I find `Grid`/`GridSplitter` a bit overengineered for everyday use when all I want is Yet Another Navigation Pane, so I recently wrote a `SplitterControl` that has two content properties and sets up the grid and splitter, with styling, in the template. I hadn't gotten around to making the split ratio persistent, so I did that just now.

What I did was rather painful because the control is configurable, and the code isn't all that great, but I can share if you're interested.

The business end is simple:

When a column resizes, set a flag to block recursion and

```
PaneRatio = _PART_ContentColumn.Width.Value / _PART_NavColumn.Width.Value;
```

When `PaneRatio` changes, if it wasn't set by the column size change handler

```
_PART_NavColumn.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
_PART_ContentColumn.Width = new GridLength(PaneRatio, GridUnitType.Star);
```

In practice, the navigator/content columns can be swapped, or they can be rows instead. Both of those are done by switching templates on a `HeaderedContentControl` that's a child of the split control template.

Comment: In other words, that value alone is not enough.  I would have to capture and restore both panels' widths to get this right.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Either that, or give up the proportional sizing and have the left (or right) column be sized by units, and make the other one `*`.